# geo location is not working on chrome browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geolocation

I want to use geo location to show content on the screen if user gave permission,

it worked fine but suddenly it does not work any more

it works fine in firefox

also does not work in the google map either, so i think it is not because of insecure websites

I'm using [GeoLocated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-geolocated) package

here is the code

```
const AddUserPage = ({ coords, isGeolocationEnabled }) => {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    if (coords) {
      setLocation({ lat: coords.latitude, lng: coords.longitude })
    }

  }, [coords])

  const changeLocation = (location) => {
   setLocation(location)
  }

  if (!isGeolocationEnabled) {
    return <div>fuck you</div>
  }
  if (coords) {
    return (
      <div style={{ width: '300px', height: "300pc" }}>
        <UserMap changeLocation={changeLocation} lat={coords.latitude} lng={coords.longitude}></UserMap>
        <Button onClick={()=>{
          console.log(location)
        }}>current location</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
  return <div>nslknl;ij'poj</div>
};

export default geolocated({
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
})(AddUserPage);
```

Comment: Any errors in dev tools or the network tab?

Comment: yeah in console i saw `Network location provider at 'https://www.googleapis.com/' : No response received.` i saw this from geolocated library at `geoPositionError` section